# Boost Binaries for MinGW

Tags: c++, boost, mingw

Are there precompiled Boost binaries for MinGW? I've tried compiling them on my own and I've encountered way too much difficulty, and at this point I'm pretty sure I've broken something vital to Windows and I'm going to figure out what two months down the road. So does anybody know where I can get a precompiled boost library to use? If not, I think I'll just wait until std::thread becomes available on MinGW.

Comment: Did you try this? Is it compiled using MSVC, not MinGW http://www.boostpro.com/download/

Comment: I don't want to use MSVC

Comment: There is a simple guide [here](http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/mingw-w64/wiki/Building%20Boost) that explain how to build boost using MinGW

Answer (score 6):

Fedora Linux 16 have them, but compiled with GCC 4.6 (C++ libraries aren't compatible between major compiler versions, Fedora 13 had Boost for GCC 4.4, Fedora 15 has for GCC4.5):

- DLLs for: [GCC 4.6](http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/fedora/linux/releases/16/Everything/i386/os/Packages/mingw32-boost-1.47.0-1.fc16.noarch.rpm) [GCC 4.5](http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/fedora/linux/releases/15/Everything/i386/os/Packages/mingw32-boost-1.46.0-0.2.beta1.fc15.noarch.rpm) [GCC 4.4](http://archives.fedoraproject.org/pub/archive/fedora/linux/releases/13/Everything/i386/os/Packages/mingw32-boost-1.41.0-1.fc13.noarch.rpm)
- Static for: [GCC 4.6](http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/fedora/linux/releases/16/Everything/i386/os/Packages/mingw32-boost-static-1.47.0-1.fc16.noarch.rpm) [GCC 4.5](http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/fedora/linux/releases/15/Everything/i386/os/Packages/mingw32-boost-static-1.46.0-0.2.beta1.fc15.noarch.rpm) [GCC 4.4](http://archives.fedoraproject.org/pub/archive/fedora/linux/releases/13/Everything/i386/os/Packages/mingw32-boost-static-1.41.0-1.fc13.noarch.rpm)

A free (as in freedom) program — [7-zip](http://www.7-zip.org/) — can open this RPM packages on Windows.

It is much easier to cross compile for Windows with MinGW32 on Fedora than to compile with MinGW+MSYS on Windows. Often it is as easy as `./configure --host=i686-pc-mingw32 && make` if you have `mingw32-*` packages installed with distribution's package manager.

A list of available packages for Fedora is [here](http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/fedora/linux/releases/16/Everything/i386/os/Packages/) — search for `mingw32`. There are compiled C and/or C++ libraries for technologies like SDL, Curl, GTK+ with Glib and Glade, Iconv, JPEG, Ogg-Vorbis, SQLite, ZIP, SSL, PCRE, Qt, Readline, Zlib and many more.

Comment: Appreciated, but this is for windows

Answer (score 6):

It seems a lot of folks have issues with MinGW and Windows when it comes to Boost. I found a great 'how-to' that helped me setup the Eclipse CDT with MinGW and Boost. Worked like a charm, no issues!

[How to setup MinGW, Eclipse CDT and Boost](http://elangovv.wordpress.com/2010/10/17/using-boost-library-in-eclipse-cdt-with-cygwin-and-mingw/)

Hope that helps. It covers both Cygwin and MinGW. I used MinGW and now I am making cross platform code in Eclipse. I am also using QMake from the Qt libraries to manage my Makefiles across the multiple platforms. Talk about comfort!

Answer (score 2):

Last week I had a need for the Boost libraries in MinGW. I couldn't find any binaries, but after some very painful debugging I managed to get them compiled myself. I eventually scrapped them and switched to Visual Studio, but I was able to pull the binaries out of my recycling bin for you (compiled with GCC 4.6 I believe):

http://daxnitro.com/mingw.zip

Hopefully they'll be useful to you.

Comment: There we no DLLs, so I'm getting "undefined reference" errors.

Comment: They're meant to be linked statically, not dynamically. Depending on what you're doing with them you would probably have to specifically point your linker to the files themselves. For example, if you're compiling a simple program with g++, you can compile with "g++ ... -L/path/to/libboost-whatever.a" or "g++ ... -lboost-whatever"

Comment: It's giving me linker errors when I do that. I'll try to debug :|